# Axios POST Request works on localhost but no longer works after deploying on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, netlify

The axios POST request was working fine on my localhost, but no longer works after deploying my site on Netlify.

The error that I receive is :

> Message not sent because of  Error: Network Error
>       at createError (webpack:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js?:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js?:81)**

Am I inputting the wrong url on the request?

*Already tried adding CORS on my server.*

What am I doing wrong :( please help!!!!

POST Request on Front-End:

```
formSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        buttonText: "...sending"
    });

    let data = {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        phone: this.state.phone,
        message: this.state.message
    };

    axios
        .post("https://www.thejunkim.com/sendmsg", data)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm());
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Message not sent because of ", err);
        });
};
```

---

SERVER:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
       "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
});

app.post("/sendmsg", (req, res, next) => {
    let data = req.body;

    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <hjk013@gmail.com>',
        to: "hjk013@gmail.com",
        subject: "SOMEONE SENT MSG FROM YOUR PERSONAL WEBSITE",
        html: output
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            console.log("Message sent: %s", res.messageId);
            console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(res));
            console.log("res", res);
            res.end();
        }
    });

    res.end();
});
```

Comment: If your `.catch` is firing on the frontend you know axios is working properly, it's your server that is throwing.

Comment: If you inspect the Network tab in the developer tools, what status code are you seeing for the request?

Comment: FWIW you are calling `res.end` inside the email callback despite the request already being complete.

Comment: It's actually giving me a 

Message not sent because of Error: Request failed with status code 404.

Does this mean that the API is not hitting?